# Need to correct the annotations to scale down and touch the donut chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, annotations

I have the following donut-plot in a 4:3 aspect ratio. I am trying to have something that is small enough that it can go alongside 4-5 similar images on a slide deck.

[image]

I used the following snippet to create annotations/labels for my wedges in the plot, however, after using `diameter = 0.8` The wedges don't touch the marker lines anymore.

```py
# Creating plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 3))
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(all_fractions_list,
                                  autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, count_of_each_type),
                                  explode=explode,
                                  shadow=True,
                                  colors=colors,
                                  startangle=90,
                                  radius=0.8,
                                  wedgeprops=wp,
                                  textprops=dict(color="black"))

# draw circle (pie chart to donut chart conversion)
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.47, fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center", size=5)

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(all_labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35 * np.sign(x), 1.4 * y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

plt.setp(autotexts, size=4, weight="normal", fontname="Verdana")
```

I'd also like to scale the names of these down to match the donut chart.